# Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence all of whose convergent proper subsequences converge to $\ell$. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\ell$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can i actually use the fact of the subsequences being proper. Are $x_{2n+1}$ and $x_{2n}$ proper subsequences? because being so solves this immediately.

Comment: How does it solve it immediately? It would do so only if you know both of those sequences converge.

Comment: Hint: you do need that the original sequence is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bounded sequence of real numbers must have at least one convergent subsequence. All of those converge to $\ell,$ and there is at least one of those; call it $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$. So for every $\varepsilon>0,$ all except finitely many terms of $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ are in the interval with endpoints $\ell\pm\varepsilon.$ If infinitely many terms of the original sequence lie outside that small interval, then that is a bounded sequence, which therefore has at least one convergent subsequence. That subsequence converges to some point outside that interval small interval. But that contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: @Mariam : Note that you can "accept" the answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was wondering if it would be possible for you to take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453786/proof-of-integral-of-a-simple-measurable-function I think you could be able to help me a great deal! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contrary.

Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ and a subsequence $(y_{n})$ of $(x_{n})$ such that $|y_{n}-l| \geq \epsilon$. But $(y_{n})$ being bounded, you can extract a convergent subsequence $(z_{n})$ from it (using Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem), which must then converge to $l$ by hypothesis: a contradiction.

Comment: so the thing is : (yn) according to assumption is actually divergent, but the Bolzano Weierstrass conveys that a bounded sequence admits infinitely many convergent subsequences and that's why it's a contradiction of the theorem? so is (yn) a representation of any subsequence of (xn)?

Comment: According to the assumption (yn) does not converge to l, but the Bolzano Weierstrass conveys that a bounded sequence (in this case yn) admits at least one convergent subsequence, which in this case should be converging to l by hypothesis. However this is not the case. (yn) is the construction of a subsequence of (xn) that does not converge to l (which can be constructed by "assuming the contrary of your result"). By the way, the proofs provided by Michael & jjj below are equivalent to mine.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the sequence does not convergent tto 1 then there exist a nbd of 1  s.t. it does not contain infinitely many term of the sequence.now,we take that terms which is outside of the nbd,and a it is a sunsequence of the sequence and as the sequence is bounded therefore the subsequence has a monotone convergent subsequence. but the subsequence does not converge to 1.its a contradiction.

Comment: by 1 i guess u mean l, and thank you